# Django - ImportError : no module named django.core.wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to deploy my Django application with Apache and mod_wsgi.

I installed and configured them according to following references:-
https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

My django project tree - /home/zahlen

```
 mysite
├── db.sqlite3
├── log
│   ├── access.log
│   └── error.log
├── manage.py
├── mysite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
├── places
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
└── static
```

django is present in `/home/zahlen/.local/lib/site-packages`

//apache2/apache2.conf

```
....
....
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIPythonPath /home/zahlen/mysite:/home/zahlen/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
<Directory /home/zahlen/mysite/mysite>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

//apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf  VirtualHost Configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    ServerAlias mysite.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.com
    Alias /static /home/zahlen/mysite/mysite
    <Directory /home/zahlen/mysite/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /home/zahlen/mysite/log/error.log
    CustomLog /home/zahlen/mysite/log/access.log combined

    <Directory /home/zahlen/mysite/mysite/>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite.com python-path=/home/zahlen/mysite
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/zahlen/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Django and mod_wsgi are configured to use **python2.7**
 . Vitualenv is **not** used and 
Apache uses the **Event MPM**

All of this is on a Ubuntu Server Virtual Machine.

//log/apache2/error.log gives the following line which verifies use of python2.7

```
....
[Sat Feb 17 02:16:45.475182 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 7282:tid 140680615626624] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
....
```

/home/zahlen/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

```
import os,sys
sys.path.append('/home/zahlen/mysite')
sys.path.append('/home/zahlen/mysite/mysite')
sys.path.append('/home/zahlen/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

My browser throws Internal Server Error on the host machine every time i open my site using ip address of the VM

//mysite/log/error.log

```
[Sat Feb 17 02:13:55.862423 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 7152:tid 139643385603840] [remote 192.168.56.1:46153] mod_wsgi (pid=7152): Target WSGI script '/home/zahlen/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Feb 17 02:13:55.862536 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 7152:tid 139643385603840] [remote 192.168.56.1:46153] mod_wsgi (pid=7152): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/zahlen/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Sat Feb 17 02:13:55.862579 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 7152:tid 139643385603840] [remote 192.168.56.1:46153] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Feb 17 02:13:55.862619 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 7152:tid 139643385603840] [remote 192.168.56.1:46153]   File "/home/zahlen/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Sat Feb 17 02:13:55.862743 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 7152:tid 139643385603840] [remote 192.168.56.1:46153]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Sat Feb 17 02:13:55.862781 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 7152:tid 139643385603840] [remote 192.168.56.1:46153] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

It seems that wsgi.py couldn't import the django package but it is present in `/home/zahlen/.local/lib/site-packages/python2.7` directory

Can anyone light me the issue please?

Answer (score 0):

Set up `sys.path` in the `wsgi.py` before you import Django module.

Comment: What are the permissions on the directory ``/home/zahlen/.local``?

Comment: Correct Permissions were set only for //python2.7 directory while `/home/zahlen/.local` was set to `drwx------  5 zahlen zahlen`. Changed it to `drwxrwx---  5 zahlen www-data` recursively and it fixed the issue. Thanks!